# Does apache poi have any dependency with xalan jar?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xalan

We are using poi for generating Excel file reports in UNIX platform.We are facing an issue while removing xalan.jar  .We couldn’t find any dependency mentioned while checking the apache poi runtime dependency page.We are using apache poi 4.1.2.

Do Apache POI have any dependency with xalan jar?
After removing the xalan .jar ,even if our xlsx is generated with same size ,but while opening we are getting the following error.

"Excel cannot open the file 'XRFWIN_410613396.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

We have extracted and compared the Excel file generated with and without xalan.

For the error scenario the xml generated is (without xalan)

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'yes'?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
<Relationship ="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument"/>
<Relationship ="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties"/>
<Relationship ="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties"/></Relationships>
```

Whereas in the success case it is generated as follows,(with xalan)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
<Relationship Id="rId1" Target="xl/workbook.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument"/>
<Relationship Id="rId2" Target="docProps/core.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties"/>
<Relationship Id="rId3" Target="docProps/app.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties"/></Relationships>
```

The error scenario does not include “id”, “target” and “Type”.

Could you please help us on this.

Comment: xerces and xalan are two XML parsers that looked up via the java **SPI** in a declarative matter, and one will be used. Check the differences, maybe xalan specific features are used. http://gonfva.blogspot.com/2012/01/things-about-xerces-xalan-and-saxon-i_18.html

Comment: What XML library are you falling back to with Xalan gone?